# Sorting a list of float with a nan

Tags: python

Please explain !
I can't even reproduce it on other computer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is based on the idea that the values being sorted form a total order. A total order requires several properties be met, including

1. for any two values `a` and `b`, exactly one of `a < b`, `a == b`, or `a > b` is true
2. the relations are transitive: `a < b` and `b < c` implies that `a < c`.

Knowing that we have a total order, we can assume that an sorted order exists, and that we can find it using O(n lg n) comparisons. In the absence of this assumption, we need to make O(n^2) comparisons to even determine *if* a sorted order exist, let alone produce one.

Floating point values with `np.nan` do *not* form a total order.

All three comparisons `np.nan < x`, `np.nan == x`, and `np.nan > x` are false no matter *what* `x` is. As a result, there is no "correct" place for `np.nan` in list; it all depends on which comparisons are made and when.